# How can I create SEO friendly url for iframe src?

Tags: php, mysql, iframe, seo

I have a video suggestion plugin [in here](http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/addvideos/type.html).
This will be open when you press ctrl+i.

I embed the videos with html files like this:

```
<iframe src="http://website.com/embeds/dragonage.html"></iframe>
```

The iframe url is come from mysql database, my table strukture looks like [this](http://i62.tinypic.com/akiq7b.png).

Now I would like to embed the videos with pretty urls, so insted of this:

```
<iframe src="http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/embeds/dragonage.html"></iframe>
```

Write out the post name in to iframe src in ordered looks like this:

```
<iframe src="http://website.com/lindsey-stirling-egy-olyan-zseniális-anyagot-dobott-össze"></iframe>
```

I readed some articles with this paramaters:

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But this not realy help, becouse the html file name and domain always differend.
So the question is:
**How can I embed videos with pretty url?**

Comment: It's no different than any other rewrite.  Using iframes does not change how your rewrite rules work.

Comment: In this state not can be work, becouse the html file name as I said always differend so I can't say in to htaccess `RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [L]` becouse the html file name can be dragonage,other or something differend.html.

Comment: So Instad I guess, I need to use some pregraplce but I don't know how.